# Crear arrayList desde lista de personas pegadas en cuadro de texto y pasarla a JList

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy en NetBeans haciendo una aplicación de sorteo en Java en la cual se ingresa el número de ganadores que va a haber (tanto titulares como suplentes, en caso de que los primeros no puedan recibir el premio), se carga la lista de nombres en el cuadro de texto y se sortea.

[image: Copia de lista de personas]

En este caso la lista de nombres la cargaría copiando los 'Me gusta' de una publicación hecha en Facebook, por lo que al copiar todo en el block de notas sale con el texto de "Agregar a amigos" abajo.

[image: Texto copiado en el block de notas o cualquier editor de texto]

La consulta es la siguiente: **¿Cómo podría hacer para copiar ese texto en el cuadro de texto del programa y al apretar en "Confirmar" me ordene los nombres en un arrayList para después hacer el sorteo?**
**Creo que lo más conveniente es que del arrayList pase un JList**, de haber otra manera mejor por favor díganme. El sorteo lo haría con Random, eso no es mucho más complicado, pero no puedo lograr lo otro.

[image: Aplicación de escritorio]

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Martin.Lo ideal sería que incluyas el código que has intentado describiendo cual parte del código no logras que funcione correctamente.

Comment: habria que ver si se tiene un patron , para poder quedarte solo con los nombres de los participantes , estaria bueno que copies varios posibles textos . a introducir para saber las variantes

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag El patrón que encuentro es ese mismo al copiar los 'Me gusta' de Facebook, como lo que muestro en la captura del block de notas. Por el momento el programa funcionaría solamente copiando y pegando desde ahí. Con que me reconozca cada salto de línea como un cambio de participante estaría bien. Lo de borrar el texto sobrante creo que podría hacerse con un `for` que vea si la primera palabra es "Agregar", un número o "Amigos" y directamente no lo tome como nombre.

Comment: ojala nadie se llame agregar o tenga de apellido amigos... eso no parece una solucion correcta..

Comment: @gbianchi sé que no es la mejor solución, en realidad no tengo demasiada experiencia y por eso acudo a Stack Overflow para tratar de resolverlo. Busqué pero no encuentro una respuesta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberiamos ir un paso para atras en tu problema.. para empezar, estan copiando y pegando a mano la lista que sale de face?? no seria mejor tratar de parsear el html?? si no es lo mejor.. por lo menos, habria que buscar un patron dentro de ese texto copiado. al parecer despues de cada linea en blanco viene un nombre.. con lo cual pareceria haber un patron simple y reconocible..

Comment: @gbianchi  Tendría que leer cómo parsear el HTML desde Java, voy a averiguar. Lo de copiarlo a mano es por una cuestión de que al hacer el sorteo se va a grabar la pantalla y mostrar que se copian todas las personas que le dieron 'Me gusta'. Sé que es rudimentario, pero lo tengo que terminar para dentro de dos o tres días y esa solución parece la que involucra menos código y complicación por el momento. Obviamente después quiero mejorarlo y que lo tome desde la publicación, así que voy a leer sobre el parseo de HTML, muchas gracias!

Comment: aunque no lo creas.. parsear un html es lo mismo que vas a hacer ahora.. que vas a parsear un txt.. solo que vas a encontrar mas "basura" en el medio...